# How do I include tailwind css in angular project

Tags: angularjs, tailwind-css

I have started learning angular and wanted to use tailwind css in my html page. I have successfully installed tailwind css via npm but when I tried to run the app after running `ng add ngx-tailwind` I faced an error.
[image]

> I am using `Angular-13.1.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nice schematic package that automatically configures Tailwind CSS, just run:

```sh
ng add ngx-tailwind
```

It'll ask you what styling preprocessor do you use and if you want to install additional plugins like `@tailwindcss/typography`

#### Manual

If you want to do it manually, since Angular 11 that should work:

```sh
npm install -D tailwindcss autoprefixer postcss
npx tailwindcss init
```

edit tailwind config to add purge as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: ['./src/**/*.{html,ts}'],
  ...
};
```

and add imports to your css:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: I tried the configure it automatically but I faced an error `An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\jbb\Desktop\tailwind css\todo-list\node_modules\tailwind.css'
See "C:\Users\jbb\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-Ifhrfs\angular-errors.log" for further 
details.` BTW my angular version is 13.1.2

Comment: Show the error log, I just tried it with clean project and everything works fine.

Comment: I have added the image in the question

Comment: I meant the content of the `angular-errors.log`, but could you show contents of your `angular.json`? If it's just new install I'd suggest just creating new solution as you already tried some solutions to add tailwindcss and maybe you've accidentialy broke something. I don't think that the error is related to the schematics.

Comment: I tried to do it with the second method I was successfully able to include tailwind css. Thanks for the help

Comment: But I am curious that how can I do it by the first method too